# Is it possible to open GitHub code in Plunker?

Tags: git, github, plunker

I have a GitHub account linked to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) but I don't see any way to open a code file or project through it. Is it possible to open GitHub files through a linked Plunker account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the current version of Plunkr.  But it looks like in their next revision, it will be available: [see this tweet.](https://twitter.com/plnkrco/status/639866094715555844)

Comment: And how is it now?